# Sql Server 2008 with Small Business Server external connector license

Tags: sql-server, windows-sbs, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Is it possible to license Microsoft Small Business Server and add an external connector license to be able to use Sql Server with a public website?

Comment: closing already answered questions with that incredibly lame "Can you help me with my software licensing question?" well played. not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the EC license does not apply to SBS.

[See here http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/external-connectors.aspx](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/external-connectors.aspx)